# Order replaced/overwritten by another order

Tags: magento-1.7

So far this issue has happened with two orders on the site.

1. User A places an order and gets their order confirmation email for order #123
2. User B places an order except that their order # is also 123.
3. User A and all traces of their order are all gone and overwritten by User B's order #123

I've searched in the database tables and order grids for the original user's name, email address, address, etc but nothing comes up at all. It's as if the entire order and everything associated with it was replaced by another order.

Both customers were billed for their orders and payment was made.

What could have happened to the original order? There's no relevant error messages in the logs. Where might be a good place to look for more info on what caused this?

---

**UPDATE**

The hosting provider was experiencing electrical issues on the same day that all the orders in question were placed on. They ended up having to restore from a backup that didn't have all the orders placed that day on it.

Magento just continued writing orders at the increment id where it left off as if nothing happened.